# LuaPlus: Register function with paramers and one return value?

Tags: c++, function, lua, return-value, luaplus

I don't really understand the system. Using `.RegisterDirect("myFunc",myFunc)` I can register a function that can't take parameters, but therefore can return a value.
Using `.Register("myFunc",myFunc)` I can register a function that can take parameters, but therefore can't return any values.

I literally spent days on this issue now and I just can't figure it out. I would really appreciate it if someone would take a look at this.

Here is [the documentation](http://wwhiz.com/LuaPlus/LuaPlus.html). Here is a quick example of how `Register` and `RegisterDirect`. Let's say I wanted the Print function to always return the string "hello". How would I do that?

```
#include "stdafx.hpp"
int Print(LuaPlus::LuaState* pState) {
    int top = pState->GetTop();
    std::stringstream output;
    for( int i = 1; i <= top; ++i ) {
        output << pState->CheckString(i) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << output.str();
    return 0; // We don't return any values to the script
}

int Get2222() {
    return 2222;
}

int main() {
    LuaPlus::LuaState* pState = LuaPlus::LuaState::Create( true );
    LuaPlus::LuaObject globals = pState->GetGlobals();
    globals.Register("Print",Print);
    globals.RegisterDirect("Get2222",Get2222);
    char pPath[ MAX_PATH ];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,pPath);
    strcat_s(pPath,MAX_PATH,"\\test.lua");
    if( pState->DoFile(pPath) ) {
        // An error occured
        if( pState->GetTop() == 1 )
            std::cout << "An error occured: " << pState->CheckString(1) << std::endl;
    }
    LuaPlus::LuaState::Destroy( pState );
    pState = nullptr;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Afaik I would have to push the value on the stack and return 1 to indicate that there is something on the stack. But that didn't seem work. I tried to add this to the function to return the number 4:

```
pState->PushInteger(4);
return 1;
```

I really hope you can help me out here.

Comment: The documentation you link to has an example of using `RegisterDirect` with a function that takes two arguments and returns a value. Does that not work for you? The example for `Register` looks like it could handle arguments and return values also (as a normal lua C function using the stack). How are you determining that your `PushInteger` snippet isn't working correctly?

Comment: No it doesn't: `luapluscd.h(211): error C2665: 'LPCD::Match' : none of the 18 overloads could convert all the argument types` All arguments are from type string.

Comment: @EtanReisner Well using const char* I at least dont get any errors, but the lua side always thinks that the return value was nil. So it doesn't work...

Comment: Include the function that is failing with that error in the original post and maybe someone can help with it.

Comment: Well, it seems to work with integers now. But how can I get it to return a string or const char* to the Lua side?

Comment: I'm barely familiar with C++ but I thought I saw overrides in luaplus for string arguments but looking at it again I don't understand anywhere near enough about the template gunk to say what is or isn't supposed to be supported. Can you get the `LOG` example from the luaplus documentation to work?